# How do I use disqus comments in github pages blog (Markdown)?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, disqus

Is it possible to integrate disqus html comments in a blog using github-pages?  I like the idea of using github, jekyll and markdown to manage my site and blog for simplicity.  However, I'd like to include disqus commenting capability.  However, since markdown generates the html - how do I include the html/js code for disqus ?

Comment: [Markdown allows raw HTML.](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) I'm not sure if GitHub Pages adds its own restrictions, however.

Comment: @MattBall: It doesn't add any restrictions.  However, you should put it in the layout file, which is usually HTML.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The easiest and cleanest way to do it is to create a partial with the HTML that disqus provides in your `_includes/` folder (e.g. `_includes/disqus.html`) and then just including it in your posts layout file (e.g. `_layouts/post.md`):

```
{% include disqus.html %}
```

You can see an example here: [post layout](https://github.com/andersonvom/andersonvom.github.io/blob/fa810729cd9cb06bcf7438d6d11d054f126d521f/_layouts/post.html#L14) and [disqus partial](https://github.com/andersonvom/andersonvom.github.io/blob/fa810729cd9cb06bcf7438d6d11d054f126d521f/_includes/disqus.html).

Comment: Right answer. Plus, you can add a `comments: true` or `comments: false` in your front matter, then surrounding the include tag with: `{% if page.comments %} ... {% endif %}`

Answer (score 15):

There is an "official" way to accomplish this task. You can find the Disqus indication at [this](https://disqus.com/admin/install/platforms/jekyll/) link. In details, the procedure is the following:

1. Add a variable called `comments` to the *YAML Front Matter* (i.e. the header of your post file) and set its value to `true`. A sample front matter might look like:

   ```
    layout: default
    comments: true
    # other options
   ```
2. Create a new template file (i.e. `disqus.html`) and put the [Universal Embed Code](https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/) there between `{% if page.comments %}` and  `{%- endif -%}`.
3. Include the `disqus.html` file into your post template.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Official Disqus link is now here: https://disqus.com/admin/install/platforms/jekyll/

Answer (score 4):

Include the disqus comment in your `post.html`, and set an identifier for the comment count link:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_shortname = '<your-disqus-name>'; 
    var disqus_identifier = '{{ page.id }}'; 
...
</script>
```

In your `default.html` template include the comment count script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = '<your-disqus-name>';
...
</script>
```

Then add the link to the comments using the `data-disqus-identifier` attribute, so that the comment count will show up after each post in your blog's main page:

```
<a href="{{post.id}}" data-disqus-identifier="{{post.id}}">Leave a comment</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Open config.yml and add the following line of code
`disqus_shortname: username`. Replace `username` with your Disqus shortname.

Create a file called `disqus_comments.html` in Jekyll’s `_includes` folder and add your Disqus Universal Embed Code in between a `{% if page.comments %}` and a `{% endif %}` liquid tag

```
{% raw %}{% if page.comments != false %}
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var disqus_shortname  = '{{ site.disqus_shortname }}';
  var disqus_identifier = '{{ page.url }}';

  (function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
{% endif %}{% endraw %}
```

You simply add `comments: false` in any posts front-matter to turn off that post comments.

Finally, open your post.html file and add the following liquid include tag just after the end `</article>` tag.

```
{% if site.disqus_shortname %}
  {% include disqus_comments.html %}
{% endif %}
```

You can follow my detailed blog post on how to [add Disqus comments to Jekyll](https://desiredpersona.com/disqus-comments-jekyll/) if you get stuck.

Answer (score 4):

To summarise:

1. Use 3rd comment service Disqus, create one its account
2. Associate your site, that is your github site, with disqus
3. Get Disqus shortname in `admin/settings/general/`
4. Edit your _config.yml of github, make sure it contains following content:

> ```
> disqus:
>     shortname: <your disqus short name>
> ```

5. Make sure there is `disqus.html` under `_includes` and it looks like:

   ```
   {% if page.comments %}
   <div class="comments">
   <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var disqus_shortname = '{{ site.disqus.shortname }}';
   (function() {
   var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
   dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
   (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq); })();    
   </script>
   <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
   </div> 
   {% endif %}
   ```

   6. Include `disqus.html` in `_layouts/post.html`
   7. To enable comment, add `comments:true` on your post yaml front matter.
      Disable it by setting `comments: false` or by not including the comments option at all.

Comment: Step 5, 6 are included into minima theme by default.

Answer (score 0):

That's true Jekyll will render HTML from your Markdown files (locally using Jekyll or remotely by pushing to gh-pages). However it doesn't really matter as this kind of code has to be in a layer, so not in the Markdown source file.

```
_layouts
    `- default.html
    `- post.html <- `layout: default` in the YAML header
_posts
    `- YYYY-MM-DD-my-post.md <- `layout: post` in the YAML header
```

By following this tree view, you'll able to render your Markdown files by using your *post* layout, which can contain your Disqus script.